# Dashboard with angular material and flexLayout

Tags: angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I'm currently building a dashboard application, and I am using AngularMaterial and flexLayout package, my application must be like this:
[image]

My application must be a responsive one if there is an idea of how to do that properly?
without adding any external packages.
Thanks for your ideas
gr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see stackblitz below, there are examples available for what you are requesting via google, this example does not have the footer, but it would be very trivial to include it and get what you are requesting.

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-menu-angular-material-flex-layout?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, how I can fix the side nav for large devices? and hide it for little ones. regards

Comment: Please post a new question about `how I can fix the side nav for large devices? and hide it for little ones.` as this question has already been answered.